# How can I check if it's my LCD or the LCD Cable that's Faulty?

Tags: lcd, dell-inspiron, laptop-display

My Dell Inspiron N5110‘s LCD Display went completely white two days ago. I was using NotePad++, when all of a sudden the image on the screen began disappearing. The way it disappeared was from top to bottom, just like the way drops of water fall on a Windows Glass.

It’s a nearly 3 years old machine that is out of warranty. This is the first problem I’ve had with it all this time. Dell Customer Care made me run a few tests like pressing <kbd>D</kbd> + <kbd>Power On</kbd> etc., and have suggested changing the LCD. I also tried a few suggestions I found online, like removing the battery and holding down the power button for 30 seconds etc., but nothings worked for me this far.

I’m thinking of buying an LCD from another place, since Dell seems to be charging way too much, and that too for refurbished parts with a 90 day warranty.

But is this really a problem with the LCD? I’ve been reading it could be the graphics card, the LCD cable, and many other things. How can I check further. I get nothing on the screen except white. No mouse pointer, no BIOS, nothing. If it isn’t a problem with the LCD, I’ll simply end up with another LCD that I’ll be able to do nothing with.

I managed to plug in an old external CRT monitor using the laptop’s VGA port, and was able to work without any problems. All my data is intact, and games run fine too. So I guess the motherboard and graphics card are okay. I suspect it’s a problem with either the LCD or the cable. But how do I find out which one is faulty?

Comment: Update : I'd shelved the Laptop from the day the screen went white, but pulled it out of it's box this morning to take a look. The screen was white shortly after power on, but to my surprise, it worked perfect once it reached the screen where you enter the password to login to Windows. I managed to save a few files to my phone, and worked normally from 10:24 to 10:48 (about 24 minutes). After that, the screen went white again. Could this mean the screen is OK, and theres a problem with the Cable? Or is there some other Software / Hardware issue?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you will use the olde external CRT monitor to get all your files off the computer before you do anything else -- just in case things get worse!

Could you try replacing parts, starting with the cheapest or most easily replaceable part first, and returning parts in their original packaging, if they don't solve the problem?